# Abbreviated function template syntax for user-defined class template argument deduction guide

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, deduction-guide

I'm writing a deduction guide in the style of an abbreviated function template, but I'm not sure if it's allowed. It compiles on gcc and clang, but not msvc.

The error is:

> error C3539: a template-argument cannot be a type that contains 'auto'

Which compiler is doing the right thing?

[try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:10,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:10,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:10,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:10,startLineNumber:16),source:%27template+%3Ctypename+Type,+int+Count%3E%0Astruct+Array%0A%7B%0A%09Type+data%5BCount%5D%3B%0A%0A++++Array+(auto+...+arg)+%7B%0A++++++++int+count+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++((data%5Bcount%2B%2B%5D+%3D+arg),...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A//+abbreviated+function+template+syntax%0AArray+(auto+first,+auto+...+next)+-%3E+Array%3Cdecltype(first),+1+%2B+sizeof...(next)%3E%3B%0A%0A//+regular+syntax%0A//+template+%3Ctypename+Type,+typename+...+Args%3E+Array+(Type+first,+Args+...+next)+-%3E+Array%3CType,+1+%2B+sizeof...(Args)%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main+()%0A%7B%0A++++Array+a(1,2,3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:64.61175236096538,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:18.721580972367963,l:%274%27,m:20.495495495495497,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:49.50706025174111,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:29.997444252763405,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:35.38824763903463,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```cpp
template <typename Type, int Count>
struct Array
{
    Type data[Count];

    Array (auto ... arg)
    {
        int count = 0;
        ((data[count++] = arg),...);
    }
};

// abbreviated function template syntax - fails in msvc
Array (auto first, auto ... next) -> Array<decltype(first), 1 + sizeof...(next)>;

// regular syntax
// template <typename Type, typename ... Args> Array (Type first, Args ... next) -> Array<Type, 1 + sizeof...(Args)>;

int main ()
{
    Array a(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: It is pretty clear from [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/auto-cpp?view=msvc-170#restrictions-and-error-messages) that msvc does not allow `auto` in parameters and template arguments in the default [`/Zc:auto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-auto-deduce-variable-type?view=msvc-170) mode. See [C3533](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3533?view=msvc-170) and [C3539](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3539?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[dcl.spec.auto.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto.general#6) any use of a placeholder type (e.g. `auto`) that is not explicitly permitted in [dcl.spec.auto] is not permitted.

And I don't see anything applying to deduction guides mentioned there. In particular [[dcl.spec.auto.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto.general#2) which allows it in function parameters is explicitly limited to parameter-declarations in function declarations and lambda expressions.

So it does seem ill-formed to me.

However, I don't see any reason for this. I suspect that [dcl.spec.auto] and the definition of *abbreviated function template* in [dcl.fct] should just be extended to include parameter lists of deduction guides with analogues rules to match the statement in [[temp.deduct.guide]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.guide) that the parameter list of a deduction guide follows the same restrictions as that of a function declaration.

Comment: Why would they want to encourage people to use this in places where you're *definitely* going to have to have a bunch of `decltype(variable_name)` instead of just using `template`? Broadly speaking, outside of lambdas, if you ever reach for `decltype` for an `auto` function parameter, you should stop and write a template header.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't really think that is a good reason to add a non-obvious syntax difference to function/constructor declarations, when deduction guides mimic them. But even so in e.g. OP's example `template<typename F> Array(F first, auto ... next) -> Array<F, 1 + sizeof...(next)>;` wouldn't need a type name or `decltype` on `next` if the use of the placeholder was allowed. (Of course you may consider mixing the styles even worse, but there should be examples where no type name is used.)